# how to correct use .properties bundle?

Tags: jsf, jstl

I tried to use jsf .properites bundle, but it does not work in my case.

```
    <fmt:setLocale value="ru"/>
    <fmt:setBundle basename="text"/>
    <fmt:message key="test"/>
```

Message not showing.
In application server log no any related messages.

text.properties and text_ru.properties content:

```
test = 123
```

My project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Where exactly did you read that `<fmt:xxx>` must work in JSF?

Comment: @BalusC https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP206

Comment: It says nothing about `<fmt:xxx>`.

Comment: @BalusC https://www.google.ru/search?q=fmt+jsf

Comment: Did you read the results you found there? I don't see anywhere that `<fmt:xxx>` must work in JSF. Try https://google.ru/search?q=jsf+localization instead.

Comment: @BalusC hmm, fmt work only in jsp?

Comment: @BalusC I'm understood, thank you